# AppCompatActivity vs. DaggerActivity

Tags: android, dagger-2

I just got a custom `Toolbar` working and then was trying to get Dagger2 in my android project and ran into `DaggerActivity` which does not extend `AppCompatActivity` which the tutorial I went through said to use.

ie. I followed these instructions https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html

Is there a way to use both then?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 8):

From the looks of the [DaggerActivity source code](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/DaggerActivity.java), it should be trivial to make a class which instead extends `AppCompatActivity`:

```
public abstract class DaggerAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements HasFragmentInjector {

  @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> fragmentInjector;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public AndroidInjector<Fragment> fragmentInjector() {
    return fragmentInjector;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`dagger.android.support.DaggerAppCompatActivity` is a part of Dagger 2.11